# How does the magnetic field expand?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-fields, charge, speed-of-light

Suppose that we have a charge. Then, we accelerate it so that it emits electromagnetic waves and is pushed back due to Abraham-Lorenz force. But, as we drop it and it starts moving at a constant velocity, it starts to generate a magnetic field that spreads at speed of light. So as the field occupies more space or volume, it increases its energy. So, if we are not giving any energy as we have dropped the charge, where does this energy come from?

Answer (score 0):

A field doesn't have energy by itself, but does work on other things that emit the same sort of field.*

Consider two conductive loops A and B separated by some large distance $s$. The loops each have a switch that starts open, so that current can't flow through them, and each is connected to its own battery that will, if the circuit is closed, cause current to flow.

Suppose we have a pair of buttons halfway between them that can turn on a current in each loop. Suppose these are the only source of magnetic fields in the universe. Position our observer with the buttons.

We push button A, closing A's circuit. Time $s/c$ later, there's a magnetic field at B. The magnetic field finds no magnetic moments, so it does no work.

Now we push button B, closing B's circuit. Immediately, B starts accelerating. The work done between the magnetic field and B comes from B's battery as part of the price of creating and maintaining the current in B. Time $s/c$ later, the magnetic field from B reaches A and A starts accelerating. The work done on A comes from A's battery as part of the cost of maintaining the current in A.

It might be fun to play with this thought experiment a bit yourself. What if we turn on A and B simultaneously? What if we switch A on and off repeatedly and leave B turned on?

---

As far as I know, it's more true to express fields as fundamental and charges as local excitations of the field. That might make some of what I've just described not entirely true, so perhaps someone can correct me.